# Tailwind - ensure dropdown list is above everything

Tags: html, css, frontend, position, tailwind-css

I'm having a problem trying to set the position of a dropdown list. I want it to be on top of everything, but when it comes into a relative positioned element, it just goes behind it. Here is a code example of what I mean.

html example:

```
  <div class="dropdown  relative">
    <button class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
      <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
      <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/> </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1">
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">One</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-b bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Three is the magic number</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown relative">
    <button class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
      <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
      <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/> </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1">
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">One</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-b bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Three is the magic number</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

live:
https://codepen.io/lcsalt/pen/MWpPvJp

How can I ensure that the list is above everything, no matter what? I tried with z-index, but didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use rule `z-index` for the `<ul>` tag. In regulation **Tailwind** there is a set of classes containing this rule.

By clicking on this [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index) you can see more details.

I added class `z-50`.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1 z-50">
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for this codepen, however, i have a more complex code in react, i tried with this z-50 and didnt work, another element that has a position relative class below is being displayed over no matter the z-index.. do you have any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: @LucasAltamirano, z-50 is z-index: 50. So your code has z-index higher than  z-index: 50. After all, Tailwind is a set of CSS styles, and it probably overlaps something. Take a look at the developer tool.

Comment: I had to set z-index: -1 as inline style property for it to work properly.. tailwinds z-0 vs z-50 wasn't working right.. wonder why